# Javascript isometric mouse over / click detection (grid XY from screenXY)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a little game in javascript, but having a problem with the isometric stuff! (early stage, I know!).

Here is what I have to convert flat grid to iso grid.

```
xs = x * (tileWidth/2) + (y * (tileWidth/2)) + offsetX;
ys = (x * (tileHeight/2)) - (y * (tileHeight/2)) + offsetY;
```

From the screen XY, how would I go about doing it?